# What is the difference between access tokens and profiles in android facebook sdk?

Tags: android, facebook

I am currently developing an android app that will make use of facebook login. I can use two classes to access user information. `Profile` and `AccessToken`. What is the difference between these?

Answer (score 1):

Profile is used to store basic user information
[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Profile/]

Access tokens give you the authority to access this information [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens]

So basically, you cannot read the profile information without the access token, and it's best to monitor the token using the AccessTokenTracker, which lets you know when the user changes their access state.
[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessTokenTracker/]